# I store hexadecimal data in a list that is of type str (for example: '0x15'),How to convert str in a list to type int

Tags: python

I want to convert the hexadecimal text data in the to a hexadecimal value, two bytes at a time, and save it in `list_1[]`. For example: convert the `150032f31d` in the `txt` text to a hexadecimal `int` and save it in the list as an `int` rather than the `str` type:

I want to `list_1 = [0x15, 0x00, 0x32, 0xf3, 0x1d]`, instead of `list_1 = ['0x15', '0x00', '0x32', '0xf3', '0x1d']`

For now, I can read out the `txt text, convert it to hexadecimal of type`str`, and put it in the list.

For example: `list_1 = ['0x15', '0x00', '0x32', '0xf3']`

I do the following:

```
def main():
f = open('ceshi1.txt','r')
list_1 = []
while True:
    c1 = f.read(2)
    if not c1:
        break
    else:
        ip_hex = hex(int(c1,16))
        list_1.append(ip_hex)
print(list_1)
```

The running result is:

['0x15', '0x0', '0x32', '0xf3', '0x1d', '0x31', '0x43', '0xc3', '0xa0', '0x16', '0x83', '0x13', '0x40', '0xd', '0xd6', '0x0', '0xa', '0xc5', '0x4a', '0x4e', '0x26', '0xf8', '0x2c', '0x29', '0x0', '0x2', '0x0', '0x54', '0x5f', '0xf3', '0x39', '0x92', '0xec', '0x2b', '0x14', '0x12', '0x0', '0x54', '0x5f', '0xf3', '0x65', '0x34', '0x84', '0xc7', '0x2c', '0xf4', '0x16', '0x0', '0x0', '0xde']

I want the data I read out of the `TXT` text to be converted two bytes at a time into hexadecimal values and stored in a list.

Comment: Please update your question with the **text** of the code you are using and its current output.

Comment: Please don't share you code as a picture, we can not run it ourselves or change it easily. Use a code tag for this if you include it in your post.

Comment: def main():
    f = open('ceshi1.txt','r')
    list_1 = []
    while True:
        c1 = f.read(2)
        if not c1:
            break
        else:
            ip_hex = hex(int(c1,16))
            list_1.append(ip_hex)
    print(list_1)

Comment: Please update your question by using the `edit` link just below the tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
>>> a = '150032f31d'
>>> [int(a[i:i+2],16) for i in range(0,len(a)-1,2)]
[21, 0, 50, 243, 29]
```

Now that does not look the same as `[0x15, 0x00, 0x32, 0xf3, 0x1d]` because when Python displays a list of integers it displays them in decimal not hex. But it is the same list, just a different representation:

```
>>> [0x15, 0x00, 0x32, 0xf3, 0x1d] == [21, 0, 50, 243, 29]
True
```

If you want Python to display a list in something other than its default representation then you need to do the formatting yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `hex` call:

```
f = open('ceshi1.txt','r')
list_1 = []
while True:
    c1 = f.read(2)
    if not c1:
        break
    else:
        ip_hex = int(c1, 16)
        list_1.append(ip_hex)
print(list_1)
```

Output:

```
[21, 0, 50, 243, 29]
```

There is no such thing as a hexadecimal int.

For example the code:

```
list_1 = [0x15, 0x00, 0x32, 0xf3, 0x1d]
print(list_1)
```

Still produces the output:

```
[21, 0, 50, 243, 29]
```